# number several equations with only one number

Tags: latex, equation, alignment

How can I number several equations in a align environment using only one number?

For example

```
\begin{align}
w^T x_i + b \geqslant 1-\xi_i \text{ if } y_i=1, \nonumber \\
w^T x_i + b \leqslant -1+\xi_i \text{ if } y_i=-1,
\end{align}
```

The numbering will appear next to the second equation. But it would be better if it appears between the lines of the two equations.

In this case how to label this group of equations for later referring to?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 82, accepted):

First of all, you probably don't want the `align` environment if you have only one column of equations. In fact, your example is probably best with the `cases` environment. But to answer your question directly, used the `aligned` environment within `equation` - this way the outside environment gives the number:

```
\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
  w^T x_i + b &\geq 1-\xi_i &\text{ if }& y_i=1,  \\
  w^T x_i + b &\leq -1+\xi_i & \text{ if } &y_i=-1,
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

The documentation of the `amsmath` package explains this and more.

Comment: A little late here, but I want to add that this doesn't work the same as the `align` environment would: it fits the box to the width of the equations, and so the space between columns is often much smaller than it would otherwise be.

Answer (score 16):

How about something like:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{A_Label}
  \begin{split}
    w^T x_i + b \geqslant 1-\xi_i \text{ if } y_i &= 1, \\
    w^T x_i + b \leqslant -1+\xi_i \text{ if } y_i &= -1
  \end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

Comment: How could you do this, but center both equations instead of anchoring them to each other?

Comment: @SpencerBoucher TeX related questions have more or less become OT here on stackoverflow. I've also not spend time with TeX lately, so I recommend you to ask your question here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/ Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Bart. tex.SO is my go-to, but this popped up on a google search. For posterity and any future Googlers, just change the \split to \gather:

`\begin{equation}\label{A_Label}
  \begin{gather}
    w^T x_i + b \geqslant 1-\xi_i \text{ if } y_i &= 1, \\
    w^T x_i + b \leqslant -1+\xi_i \text{ if } y_i &= -1
  \end{gather}
\end{equation}`

Comment: @SpencerBoucher The inner environment should be `gathered` instead of `gather`.

Comment: @JonasStein it was an image, but was removed. Added a new one using https://quicklatex.com

Answer (score 0):

Gathered environment can be used as well to have everything centered.

```
\begin{equation}
  \begin{gathered}
  w^T x_i + b &\geq 1-\xi_i &\text{ if }& y_i=1,  \\
  w^T x_i + b &\leq -1+\xi_i & \text{ if } &y_i=-1,
  \end{gathered}
\end{equation}
```