# Latex - Unwanted labels appearing on my equation

Tags: latex

This is my code:

```
\begin{align}
Position_{increment}(t) &= K_{P1}.(Tension_{limit} - Sensor(t)) \\
&+ K_{P2}.(Sensor(t) - Sensor_{opposite}(t)) \\
&+ K_I.\sum_{0}^{t}(Tension_{limit} - Sensor(t)) 
\label{equation:position_PI}
\end{align}
```

And this is the output:

[image]

Note that I only want one label to appear.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599825/number-several-equations-with-only-one-number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider using `aligned` inside an `equation`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  Position_{increment}(t) &= K_{P1}.(Tension_{limit} - Sensor(t)) \\
  &+ K_{P2}.(Sensor(t) - Sensor_{opposite}(t)) \\
  &+ K_I.\sum_{0}^{t}(Tension_{limit} - Sensor(t)) 
\end{align}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    \text{Position}_{\text{increment}}(t) &= K_{P1} \cdot \bigl( \text{Tension}_{\text{limit}} - \text{Sensor}(t) \bigr) \\
    &\phantom{{}={}} + K_{P2} \cdot \bigl( \text{Sensor}(t) - \text{Sensor}_{\text{opposite}}(t) \bigr) \\
    &\phantom{{}={}} + K_I \cdot \sum_0^t \bigl( \text{Tension}_{\text{limit}} - \text{Sensor}(t) \bigr) 
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I've updated the spacing around the missing `=` relation to reflect what it should look like. Also, if you're using text in equations, then use `\text`, or create your own "variable macro" `\var{<stuff>}`, for [consistency](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29846/5764):

```
\newcommand{\var}{\text}
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for, via `\nonumber` or `\notag`?:

[image]

```
\begin{align}
Position_{increment}(t) &= K_{P1}.(Tension_{limit} - Sensor(t)) \\
&+ K_{P2}.(Sensor(t) - Sensor_{opposite}(t)) \nonumber \\
&+ K_I.\sum_{0}^{t}(Tension_{limit} - Sensor(t)) \nonumber
\label{equation:position_PI}
\end{align}
```

From one of the answers to this [related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2597/how-do-i-turn-off-equation-auto-numbering).

Answer (score 0):

A third solution may be:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
    Position_{increment}(t) &= K_{P1}.(Tension_{limit} - Sensor(t)) \\
    &+ K_{P2}.(Sensor(t) - Sensor_{opposite}(t)) \\
    &+ K_I.\sum_{0}^{t}(Tension_{limit} - Sensor(t))
    \label{equation:position_PI}
  \end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

as suggested in section 3.2 of [this manual](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf).